# How to bind StackPanel content with a list of Images

Tags: c#, wpf, list, data-binding, stackpanel

I'd like to know if there is a way to bind StackPanel children with a List of image declared programmatically? Or even duplicate one image by specified number using DataTemplate the same way as it is used in ListBox where you can define a DataTemplate of  ListBoxItem and it is duplicated automatically by the number of the listboxitems...

Comment: Is it a homework for us?? Do you have any code for it?

Comment: I don't have a code I'm asking theoretically so I could start codin

Answer (score 3):

Use an `ItemsControl`. This has a built-in `StackPanel` to display it's items (called the `ItemsPanelTemplate`).

The `ItemsControl` has a `DataTemplate` and can be bound to an `IEnumerable` (`ItemsSource`).

Comment: And where do I tell the StackPanel how many duplicates I want of that Template?

Comment: That's the amount of items in the ItemsSource.